# Integral with U-Substitution (Volume of Revolution)

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve a problem.

Let $S$ be the part of the paraboloid of revolution $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ where $z \leq 9$.

Compute the integral $$\int_S (x^2+y^2+3z^2)|d^{2}x|$$

I have set this up with the transformation ($u$, $v$, $u^2+v^2$), with $det(D^{T}D)$ equal to $(1+4u^{2}+4v^{2})^{1/2}$. Converting to polar coordinates, we have $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{3}(r^{2}+3r^{4})(1+4r^{2})^{1/2}rdrd\theta$$ But I fail to see how it is possible to solve this integral using u-substitution. 
Any help would be much appreciated.